# Laravel - use checkbox to display data in datatables using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, datatables

I want to filter using checkbox, so if checkbox is checked filter data in datatables where data in column "details"= checkbox value and so on

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box20" value="slip">
<table id="users-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Details</td>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('#users-table').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: 'student/get_datatable',
      columns : [
          {data: 'details'},
          {data: 'Description'},
      ],
  });
  });
</script>
```

**controller:**

```
public function get_datatable()
{
  return Datatables::eloquent(Orders::query())->make(true);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: its clear, I want to show data in datatable using ajax when check the checkbox, just make checkbox to filter data!